# Error when launching uvc_camera

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, uvc-cam, ros-package-path, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am currently trying to use uvc_camera with my project but when i launch it i get this error with my codes.
( This are my error)

```
NODES
/
camera_node (uvc_camera/camera_node)
find_object_2d (find_object_2d/find_object_2d)
objects_detected (find_object_2d/objects_detected)

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_camera/camera_node]: uvc_camera
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros 
ROS path [1]=/home/anna/ASD/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Would appreciate anyone that is able to help! Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201109/error-when-launching-uvc_camera/) by [Anna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20162/anna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two common causes for problems like this:

1. You don't have the uvc_camera package installed. Try installing it by using `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-uvc-camera`
2. You've checked out the uvc_camera package from source, but haven't compiled it. Either compile it, or remove it from your workspace and install it through apt (see #1)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20162/anna/) on 2015-01-18**:
Hi sir, how do we edit the uvc_camera launch folder to launch a usb camera asus xtion pro live. Awesome help by the way thanks in advance!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-18**:
The Asus Xtion Pro Live isn't a normal USB camera; you should use the openni or openni2 drivers for it. If you're having trouble with it, please ask a new question.